# When if/else condition is true, executes code in true and false blocks

Tags: swift, if-statement

Having something really strange happen, and I don't understand how it's even possible.  I'm new to swift, so I may be missing something. I can post more code if needed, but regardless of what else I'm doing, how could this ever happen?

```
    if sender.on {
        txtNumMavericks.hidden = false
    } else {
        txtNumMavericks.hidden = true
    }
```

In this case, the sender is a switch.  When the switch is false, just the second part of the block runs, as expected.  But when it is true, it executes both the top and bottom statements (makes txtNumMavericks appear and then immediately disappear).  I found this by putting a breakpoint above the if statement single stepping through the code with F6.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is actually executed, you should put a print statement to both parts of the if statement, and see the result in the console log. Stepping with F6 could sometimes be very strange...

Comment: You're right.  When I add the println, it only executes the one in the correct brackets, but i am still having the problem that the txtNumMavericks hides or stays hidden no matter if the switch is on or off.

Comment: Haha.  I figured out the issue!  I had the same switch tied to two different functions.  Thank you for the help.  That F6 behavior really threw me off!

Comment: yeah, there are some "features" in the compiler to be fixed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to toggle those properties all you have to do is to add an exclamation mark "!" in front off the actual property as follow:

```
txtNumMavericks.hidden = !txtNumMavericks.hidden
```